# Server 2012 R2: Remote Desktop Services, certificates, and internal .local domain

Tags: certificate, remote-desktop-services

Without a unique, publicly-resolvable Active Directory domain (i.e. using foo.local vs. corp.foo.com), is it possible to achieve RDP certificate/SSO Nirvana? i.e. end-to-end, zero nag, RDP sessions (RemoteApp + Remote Desktop) *without* requiring client-side certificate installation.

I want to keep this high-level: I can work through the planning/configuration process (and ask additional questions as required), but before I go down this road (vs. looking at alternatives like Citrix), I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Interesting question, I'll be interested to hear peoples experiences.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting my hopes up.

Comment: Are you worried about the act of installing the certificates? You could always push those with GPO with minimal manual intervention required..

Comment: @Rex or he's got a large number of non-Windows clients that aren't going to be able to get a certificate via GPO.  (Been there, done that, burned the T-shirt.)

Comment: @HopelessN00b quite true - Don't know quite enough about what problem he's trying to solve by circumventing the client-side certificate requirement.. poor t-shirts..

Answer (score 1):

*Without* installing certificates on your clients?  Then the answer is simply no.  No. No.

However, it's possible *iff* you distribute the root certificate used for the RDP sessions to every client who will be making those RDP connections.

If I have a domain called INamedMyDomainPoorly.local, no globally-trusted certificate authority such as Godaddy or Cybertrust is going to issue a certificate for that.  But I can easily stand up my own internal certificate authority, ca.INamedMyDomainPoorly.local, have it issue a certificate for rdsessionhost.INamedMyDomainPoorly.local, and then add the root CA's cert (and chain if applicable) to the Trusted Root CA store on all my clients.

I could distribute this certificate with Group Policy if all my clients are joined to an Active Directory domain.

The certificate would need to accurately reflect the hostname of the RD session your clients are connecting to, your clients need DNS resolution for INamedMyDomainPoorly.local, and it needs to include a CDP (CRL Distribution Point(s)) that is accessible by your clients.

Comment: was doing a -1 before your edit only because he specifically said "without requiring client-side certificate installation" and you specifically said you would need to distribute the certificate to every client. Solution is right, but wouldn't meet his needs

Comment: Thanks for your input. I suddenly feel like I'm taking an MCSE certification exam. :P

Comment: Why can't you register INMDPoorly.com and create remotedesktop.INMDPoorly.com and have that resolvable internally and externally and have the SSL certificate with that name in it? You don't need to rename the domain itself, just make the new name resolvable and have the RDS Session host configured to answer to that name. (I haven't tried this, but I think it ought to work).

Comment: Lots of pompous guff in there, but yes, I'm with you @RyanRies.  One small revision: the domain is actually SomeOtherIdiotNamedTheDomain.local.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I've actually tried that; doesn't want to connect (even with a hosts file on the RDS "sandwich", as all roles are currently running on the same server; who knows what kind of proxy/loopback convulsions the server is going through...) and yes, it should be separated out to different roles, with RDS Gateway in a DMZ, with armed guards, and...